# EC2 docker container nginx port outside access issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running nginx in a docker container in an EC2 instance. I started nginx using  `docker run --name mynginx1 -p 80:80 -d nginx` and can access it via `curl http://localhost` from inside the EC2 instance. Now when I try to access it from my outside through my browser, my request is always timing out. I have set the security rules on my EC2 instance to allow all traffic, all protocols from any IP address for the purpose of testing.

I have verified that nginx is listening on any IP address using `ss -tuln | grep 80`

```
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096              0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                 [::]:80            [::]:*
```

Any ideas?

Note: When I install nginx on EC2 directly and run it using `sudo systemctl start nginx`, I am able to go to http://<ec2_dns> and see the nginx welcome page. So I believe this is an issue specific to running docker containers on EC2 and not a problem with the instance security rules.

Edit 1: Subnet network ACLs inbound rules are as follows:
[image]

Comment: did you try to do both scenarios on the same EC2?

Comment: @DerekMenénedez Yes

Comment: Are you trying to access it via Public DNS or Private DNS? and does it work with Public IP : Port ?

Comment: Are you accessing it via http and not https?

Comment: Have you checked your subnet NACLs?

Comment: @Paolo How should I check the subnet NACLs and what should I look for?

Comment: @saurabh14292 I'm trying to access it via public DNS. It works in the case where I installed nginx directly.

Comment: @Riz verified that I'm accessing it via http

Comment: What are the inbound rules for the network acl for the subnet where your instance is deployed?

Comment: @Paolo Updated the question with a screenshot of subnet NACLs.

Comment: @user2464953 ok, that's not it then. does the subnet route table have a route to an internet gateway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245084/discussion-between-user2464953-and-paolo).